# Cannot select faces

Tags: faces, selection-tools, select

I want to select faces on a simple cube in blender. But no matter where I click, nothing gets selected. Even drawing a selection box over the whole object does not select any face.

[image: Selection not working]

Comment: Your active object is _Bottom_, see yellow highlighted icon in the outliner. Switch to object mode and make _Side2_ the active object to edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can happen if you select more than one item and the other item is not editable like a light.

Go back to edit mode, click on an empty area, then select your box again and go to edit mode. Then it should work.